# button created sprite class want to add Event.trigger to that button in another screen class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, starling-framework

```
public class MyQuad extends Sprite
{
    public var quad:Quad;
    private var lbl:Label;
    public function MyQuad(lbl1:String,quadx:int,quady:int,lblx:int,lbly:int,btnx,btny)
    {
        super();
        quad=new Quad(100,100,Color.WHITE);
        this.addChild(quad);
        quad.width=100;
        quad.height=75;
        quad.x=quadx;
        quad.y=quady;

        lbl=new Label();
        lbl.text=lbl1;
        lbl.x=lblx;
        lbl.y=lbly;         
        this.addChild(lbl);

        var btn:Button=new Button(Assets.getTexture("Add"));
        btn.width=30;
        btn.height=30;
        btn.x=btnx;
        btn.y=btny;
        this.addChild(btn);         
    }
}
```

I have a class, `sprite`, that contains many display objects (quad,label,button). I call this class in another one which extends `screen`.  In the class that extends screen I want to add a trigger event to the button in the sprite class.  How can I call that button or the trigger event of that button?

Comment: At least variables should be visible to the classes which will inherit. You could also create methods which will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the button accessible publicly. There's a few ways to do this, but the most straight forward is to do it the way you've already done with the variable `quad`.

For example:

```
public class MyQuad extends Sprite
{
    // ... other class variable definitions
    public var btn:Button;

    public function MyQuad(lbl1:String,quadx:int,quady:int,lblx:int,lbly:int,btnx,btny)
    {
        super();
        // Set up your other items
        btn = new Button(Assets.getTexture("Add"));
        // Set the properties on your Button as usual
    }
}
```

Since you have now defined the `btn` as a `public var` in your class, this will now be accessible publicly through a reference to an instance of this class.

For example:

```
var myQuad:MyQuad = new MyQuad(...);
myQuad.btn.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onButtonTriggered);

function onButtonTriggered(e:Event):void {
    // Handle button triggered event
}
```